# Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-29 Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

When I create a new flutter project, it creates project with `compileSdkVersion 29` for android, but when I run the flutter application, it runs for long time and build failed with below error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':geolocator:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-29

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

But after explicitly change the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 29, even then I'm also getting the same error.

Comment: Just want to double confirm the android sdk 29 have downloaded and accepted the agreement already?

Comment: open android studio sdk tools and check if you have sdk 29 installed

Comment: SDK platform or SDK tools?, FYI (28,29,30 SDK tools is already installed.)